# Using an XSD from dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a webservice that will be referring to an XSD file that is in another project (imported as a dependency). I am able to pull the XSD in using the plugin in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082407/distribute-xsd-files-over-multiple-maven-artifacts). However, this pulls it directly into the source. I would rather have it added to the build directory to avoid committing the file.

If I extract the xsd to my existing project structure:

```xsd
<outputDirectory>schema</outputDirectory>
```

It shows up in the .jar. However, if I extract it to the build directory:

```xsd
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated/schema</outputDirectory>
```

It does not show up in the .jar (even if I add it to the build path).

I think I am missing some fundamental understanding of the maven lifecycle. What do I need to do in order to get a file into the .jar while keeping the file in the build directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Maven Resource Plugin` in order to add additional resources (that will be packed into final archive) and which are not into the usual resource directory aka *src/main/resources/*:

```xml
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated/schema</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Comment: Is there any way to tell Maven that I want to use this directory in addition to the directories that are already defined? This snippet is actually overriding them.

Comment: Where does those directories are defined? You can provide as many `<resource>` directories as you want, so that won't be that hard.