Building a maven project with xsd's which reference another project's xsd's
I have a common base project:
This project builds a jar file containing classes generated from multiple xsd's.  The classes are referenced by other projects when constructing their jars.
common-domain
       src/main/resources/xsd/XBase.xsd
       src/main/resources/xsd/XCode.xsd
       ...

I can build common-domain just fine but I have projects which depend on these xsd's.  Such as:
common-dependent
   src/main/resources/xsd/MySample.xsd

MySample.xsd contains the line <xs:import schemaLocation="XBase.xsd" namespace="bob://XBase"/>
I don't know how to build the common-dependent project providing the dependency on XBase.xsd.

Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082407/distribute-xsd-files-over-multiple-maven-artifacts

I just tried that solution.  But yes an exact dup.
